# Required attribute for complex objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, editortemplates, model-validation

I have a class like this

```
public class PageReference {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and in my model I use it like this

```
[Required]
public PageReference PageLink { get; set; }
```

the required attribute does not fire if I add it to the pagelink property, how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

The validation attribute is evaluated by the model binder against the data supplied by the value provider (often posted form fields).  If you're posting a form that does not include that field, the binder won't touch that property of the model and so won't evaluate the validation attributes.

Answer (score -2):

I think there is no recursive validation support in asp.net mvc